# RAP ontology centric model from owl file

Tags: php, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

For the past few days I'm struggling with the RAP API library.
Basically I've created an custom ontology which I want to use with this library, as they state it supports to work with ontologies.

But the **load()** method from the library generates some weird **OntModel**.

This is the code where I try to load my ontology:

```
 $client = ModelFactory::getOntModel (MEMMODEL,OWL_VOCABULARY);
 $client->load("myOntology.owl");

 $querystring = '
 SELECT ?model
 WHERE ( ?Brand, <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/proj.owl#hasModel>, ?model )';

 $result = $client->rdqlQuery($querystring);
 rdqlEngine::writeQueryResultAsHtmlTable($Result);
```

Can someone help me ? On the RAP API library documentation they have an example describing only how to create an ontology, not how to read one from an file(or external URI).

Thanks in advance.

**Later Edit**

---

Here is the OntModel which was loaded: [OntModel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5H_4u9qwNOjY19pUjQ1N05uTGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is that query string supposed to be SPARQL?  It isn't.

Comment: And what's the actual problem?  You've said that "the load() method from the library generates some weird OntModel."  Isn't that what you'd want?  An Ont(ology)Model?  Is somethign not working about it?  Does it not contain the triples you'd expect?

Comment: I displayed the actual content of the model and it contains lot of BlankNodes ... not a single property I've actually set in my ontology wasn't visible, but maybe I can't display it and I have to actually query it.

Do you know how to query it ? Not even the RAP method to list it's classes isn't working (it's giving errors, will post them later when I can run the script again)

Answer (score 0):

Open Ontology in Protege and save it as "RDF/XML" instead of "OWL/XML" as I had done initially.